# In jQuery, how would I append a style align left to ALL elements?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to have jQuery append a style="text-align: left;" to **all** elements on my page.

I know I would probably have to do something like:

```
$('everything-in-the-page').each( ...
```

But I'm a little confused as to how I can select every HTML tag.

**JUST TO STOP THE BACKLASH:**
This is for an accessible site (print only). So, ***YES*** I ***KNOW*** it's bad practise.

Comment: Why not do this in your base CSS if it's going to apply to *every* element?

Comment: What are you after here?  Putting a css class on *every* element isn't a good solution...what's the actual problem? There's probably a better way to solve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
$('*').css('textAlign', 'left');
```

Comment: Since this was accepted - to save future googlers.... **Styles cascade** (CSS, *cascading* style sheets), applying it *once* to the `<body>` in CSS will do the job, not sure what the focus on making this perform as slow as possible is.  `text-align` on a parent goes (cascades) to the child, `$('body').css('text-align', 'left');` would be all you needed to do this, if you have specific elements that have another `text-align` property applied, select those, but selecting everything is *rarely*, if **ever**, a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

If you **need** to do this (please don't, it's a *really* bad idea for a few reasons, performance for starters):

```
$('*').css('text-align', 'left');
```

But it seems like just a single CSS rule would do the job:

```
body { text-align: left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using **`*`** as CSS selector, if you want to indicate *everything* ?

i.e. :

```
$('*').each(...
```

As a reference, you can take a look at [5.3 **Universal selector**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector) *(quoting)* :

> The universal selector, written "`*`",
>   matches the name of any element type.
>   It matches any single element in the
>   document tree.

Comment: @Nick : yes, probably -- didn't think to say it, so, thanks for the comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('*').each(...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a print-only style, you can still use CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

JavaScript isn't a good way to achieve better accessibility - your will better work well even with JavaScript disabled.

More details: [A List Apart - CSS Design: Going to Print](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/)